# An error occurred... Microsoft Exchange WebServices... when developing SharePoint 2013 in VS 2013

Tags: 2013, development-enviroment

I have a development environment setup with these components

- SharePoint 2013
- Windows 2012 R2
- Visual Studio 2013

SharePoint is up and running just fine.

I am however getting an error when trying to add SharePoint items to my solution in the Visual Studio project.

> An error occurred while trying to load a required component. Please
>   ensure that the following prerequisite component is installed:
>   Microsoft Exchange WebServices

[image]

I have tried the well known `EwsManagedApi32.msi addlocal="ExchangeWebServicesApi_Feature,ExchangeWebServicesApi_Gac"` from an elevated command prompt. This error rather seems to be that VS 2013 don't recognize the EWS assemblies.

Any advices are welcome, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you install just the developer tools without the complete set of prerequisites. You could try fixing your setup by closing Visual Studio and then following steps:

1.Go to Control Panel > Uninstall a program
2.Select Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012
3.Click on Change to uninstall it. The setup program should launch.
4.Click on Uninstall to remove the Office Developer Tools.
5.Download the Office Developer Tools using this Web Platform Installer link from the Get It Now section of the blog announcing the latest release of Office Developer Tools. This Web Platform Installer should install the Office Developer Tools and all the prerequisites (Exchange Web Services, LightSwitch HTML Client, etc).
6.Try creating your SharePoint 2013 Empty Project again.

[Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f76575e2-b394-4cf8-b0e4-9a4b23250d51/microsoft-web-developer-tools-and-exchange-web-services?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: Thanks, but this is VS 2013 and id does not require the Office Developer Tools package, it isn't even possible to install it.

Comment: There most certainly is an Office Developer Tools package for VS 2013 that causes this error if it's missing.

Comment: I am trying to create new project in VS2015 with SP 2016 installed, but the issue is similar- in my case I believe , have to install latest Office Developer Tools which should resolve the issue.

Comment: @JohnZachariah did u find a fix as today i install VS 2015 community and i am facing this problem !!

Comment: No , I didn't actually within corporate, the firewall did not allow me to do web deployer, but using web deployer this could be resolved..

Comment: Update: I re-installed Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0 that helped fixing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and Reinstalling Visual Studio 2013 solved this issue.

Comment: This saved my day!, I am trying to create new project in VS2015 with SP 2016 installed, but the issue is similar- in my case I believe , have to install latest Office Developer Tools which should resolve the issue.

Comment: Update: I re-installed Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0 that helped fixing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and re-installed Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0 with 64 bit version that helped fixing the issue.

This reference give you step by step installation [Link](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/01/an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-load-a-required-component-please-ensure-that-the-following-prerequisite-component-is-installed-microsoft-exchange-webservices/)

[Microsoft Link to download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35371)